# Difference between web.config and cscfg file?

Tags: web-config, azure-webapps, cscfg

I have an azure webapp which currently uses web.config file. I wanted to know if it is possible to create cscfg file for a webapp? If yes, what is the difference between web.config and cscfg configuration file and which one is preferred?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Service Configuration Schema file -The cloud service configuration file (.cscfg) provides configuration settings for the cloud service and individual roles, including the number of role instances,and the thumbprints for any certificates associated with a role.

Configuration settings for a role are defined in the ServiceDefinition.csdef file and the values for the settings are configured in the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file.
Service Configuration file (*.cscfg) can be thought of as web.config equivalent for your roles (Web and Worker) relevant for Cloud Service. 
You must use web.config file App Service. 
There are some good discussion on this topic, you may wish to checkout these [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591367/service-definition-vs-service-configuration-in-azure-cloud-services) and [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449761/webconfig-overrides-for-azure-cloud-services).